# CAKEPHP: Get the Value of Data Array in form

Tags: php, cakephp

This is the form code:

```
 <h2>Upload your file from here</h2> 
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo WEBSITE_PATH; ?>users/enter_text" id="si_upload_form">
 <input type="file" name="file" class="home_single_upload">
 </form>
```

created hidden field to display time and file name

```
 <?php
 echo $this->Form->hidden('time_val',array('value' => '','id'=>'time_val'));
 echo $this->Form->hidden('filename_val',array('value' => '','id'=>'filename_val'));
 ?>
```

How can I retrieve the value in the hidden form. I want it to set in a variable, and display it.

Comment: is it possible to set it in a variable like $myTime ?

Comment: `$myTime=$_POST['time_val'];`

Answer (score 0):

`$myTime = $_POST['time_val'];`

Don't forget your other hidden input and also don't forget to set those values in your form

Ok, from CakePHP docs:

> FormHelper::hidden(string $fieldName, array $options)
>    Creates a hidden form input. Example:

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('id');
```

Will output:

```
<input name="data[User][id]" id="UserId" type="hidden" />
```

So you need to be using

```
$_POST['data[User][time_val]']
```

You can easily see what `$_POST` values you should be using by either
1. Looking at the source of the page, or 
2. `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: i did like this

 $myFiletype = $_POST['filename_val'];
 echo $myFiletype;

and it gives me an error Undefined index: filename_val

im using cakephp by the way.

Comment: that will do it, but still don't forget to fill in those values or else they will both be blank

Comment: when i switch from hidden to text i already see the time and the file name. i just want it to store in a variable. so i can freely use it.

Comment: the form in is in index.ctp and i want it to display in my myview.ctp

what is user in 
    $_POST['data[User][time_val]']

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what that means, but maybe you should take a look at the CakePHP docs

Comment: i tried 

$myFiletype = $_POST['data[filename_val][filename_val]'];
echo $myFiletype;

in my myview.ctp but still gives me an undified index.